# Laravel Unautheticated on every API on other server

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I am using Laravel 7 with latest Passport to authenticate my APIs.

It was working fine on system where it was created but after cloning to other local system and also production server it stopped working.

**I am getting Unautheticated error every time.**

**What I have tried:**

1. I have searched for this error and visited all the top ten results and multiple questions on SO but in vain.
2. htaccess is already having following code:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
   RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
   ```
3. My API route file looks as below:

   ```
   Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
       return $request->user();
   });

   // passport
   Route::group([
       'prefix' => 'auth'
   ], function () {
       Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
       Route::post('signup', 'AuthController@signup');
       Route::post('verify', 'AuthController@verify');
       Route::post('reset', 'AuthController@reset');
       Route::group([
         'middleware' => 'auth:api'
       ], function() {
           Route::get('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
           Route::get('user', 'AuthController@user');
       });
   });
   ```
4. I have ran following command to install passport on new system:

   `php artisan passport:install`
5. OAuth tables are present in database.
6. Then I tried removing Passport and tried running **public API request even then I am getting Unautheticated error.**
7. My web authentication is working fine.
8. Also changed the guards.api to passport.
9. Already tried `php artisan optimize:clear`

After spending around 2 days came here.

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try clear your config cache?  `php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: @Egretos already tried

Comment: facing the same issue, did you solve it @Egretos